# Is there any way by which i can know if the recipient have replied to my email or not?

Tags: javascript, email, amazon-ses

I have set up an email tracking system in my application, that shows how many emails I have sent, how many emails have been read., and the emails I am sending is via AWS SES. I want to know is there a way via which I can know if the client has replied back?

Comment: Looks like you can have incoming messages from SES published to an SNS feed: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-receive-and-process-incoming-email-with-amazon-ses/

Answer (score 0):

To know how many emails were read/opened, you can use SES feature called "Open".
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/open-and-click-tracking-have-arrived/
You need to make use of configuration set to do that and this can enable either Cloudwatch metric or you can have SNS trigger when there is any open event, SES will add a link at the bottom of your HTML body which is a 1 pixel image but the should contain HTML body(html part).

To know how many people have replied back to the email can be tricky. First of all, you're sending emails via SES but when they reply back, does the sender/reply-to address domain points to SES incoming mails ? example: does your domain has mx pointed to SES incoming email endpoint, if so you can use SNS trigger what IceMetalPunk mentioned, but if you don't use SES to receive email, there is no way.
The best option would be to use a subdomain as a sending domain and receive emails to S3 if Main domain is acquired to receive emails to mailboxes.